# How to clean git commit log before push?

Tags: git, github

I want to combine several commit into one commit.

```
git checkout origin/develop -b develop
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature A commit 1"
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature B commit 1"
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature A commit 2"
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature B commit 2"
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature A commit 3"
echo "a" >> README && git commit -am "Feature B commit 3"
```

Before I push, I want to combine `Feature A commit 1,2,3` into one commit `Feature A commit`, and same as `Feature B`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to make that is the following:

```
git rebase -i <ref>
```

This command will open your editor and show you every possible options to reorder/squash/rename... your commits.

Hope this will help you.

Here is the documentation about git rebase: [git-rebase](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Or just google git squash.

I don't have computer in hand and so cannot try it for you.